# Sumar los NA por grupo en r (sin las funciones apply, lapply, etc)

Tags: r

Intento sumar los NA por grupo y crear un `data.frame` que tenga el grupo y la cantidad de NAs.

Ejemplo: del siguiente set:

```
Group Value
A        4
A        4
B        NA
B        4
```

Necesito obtener:

```
Group #NA
A      0
B      1
```

Comment: Por favor traduce la pregunta a Español :)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en otro idioma

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿por qué no puedes usar las funciones `apply`, `lapply`,...?, ¿qué has intentado hacer?,¿es una tarea de la universidad/colegio?

Comment: Efectivamente, es una tarea de capacitación.  Intenté lo siguiente **> with(data,aggregate(val~nom,FUN=is.na))** pero no sirvió puesto que el resultado es:  
  nom          val  
1   A FALSE, FALSE  
2   B        FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Estimados. He logrado resolver el problema gracias a unos amigos, comparto la solución:

```
data<-data.frame(Group=c("A","A","B","B"),Value=c(4,4,NA,4))  

with(data,aggregate(Value,list(Group),function(x){sum(is.na(x))}))

 Group.1 x  
1       A 0  
2       B 1
```

Comment: Si esta fue la solución a tu problema, deberías marcarla como aceptada haciendo click en el **✅** a la izquierda de la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solucion con dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(Group=c("A","A","B","B"), 
                   Value=c(4,4,NA,4))

data %>%
  mutate(nas = ifelse(is.na(Value), 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarize(sum(nas))
```